# Insert <br /> into php file within <html> tag?

Tags: php, html

Good morning, 
I try to inset `<br />` tag into my html file, what am i doing wrong here ? it don't work. I get line-break instead code format like above.

```
  <code><br /></code>
```

Ps. Its standard index.php

Answer (score 0):

no need for the /, assuming you're referring to a simple .html file

```
<BR>
```

the only time i've seen the need for extra / characters is if you are having the html code generated by PHP or similar, and you need to exclude specific characters from being recognized as a command by the generating entity PHP/Perl/etc

Comment: <br /> comes from XHTML it have really no difference if you use with / or without

Comment: if you're referring to inserting a line-break within the output generated by PHP, you don't need excluding characters anymore.

Comment: its really no difference if you use <br> or <br /> i tried to change it to standard html 5 br but its not a problem here :)